# GUI Based Perf Events Analysis Tools

Tags: linux, open-source, performance-analysis

I am looking for a GUI tool for perf events in Linux? https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

This would be akin to kcachegrind for callgrind.

I know that Intel VTune could do this, but I was hoping for something open source.

Comment: While not open source, I discovered that Oracle has free compilers and profiling tools for Linux and Solaris here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AMD CPU, you can try [AMD CodeXL.](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/)

An alternative would be to use any of the existing standard linux profilers available and plot the output using utilities like [this.](https://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot)

Comment: AMD's CPU profiler was moved to its GPUOpen suite and is now part of https://developer.amd.com/amd-uprof/ (be aware that the later needs a "Zen" based processor).

Answer (score 1):

Quite a new tool called [Hotspot](https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot), which provides UI around Linux perf, is available on GitHub. Unfortunately, it is not available in standard Linux repositories yet, but you can easily download an AppImage [here](https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot/releases) or build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/zoom/). On systems that support it, it uses Perf as a backend. The results in `butterfly` profile view are very similar to those displayed by Perf ncurses 'GUI' (except that you get callees on top of callers) or Callgrind. Not open source, though.